# Add channels to / edit existing tdms files?

Tags: python, labview, h5py

I have a naive question but did not manage to find a clear answer. I have some .tdms files with channels of data. I would like to add additionnal channel of data in this tdms file (for example in Python take 2 existing channels and go: "newChannel = channel_1 + channel_2" and add this newChannel to my tdms file).

I did not find any way to edit / add data to a tdms file, is that even possible ? For now I just create .h5 files for each tdms file (on which I can add data), but they take more space than the .tdms for the same amount of data (that's why I'm interested to work directly on the .tdms).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to update that TDMS file with LabVIEW or Python ?
With Labview you can simply open the file and write your new data in your new channel using the TDMS write VI function :

[image: Write in TDMS with LabVIEW]

If you want to edit your TDMS files with python you should try https://pypi.org/project/npTDMS/ (never tried it myself as it's so well integrated in LabVIEW)